# Drupal 8 allow only listed languages

Tags: 8, i18n-l10n

Is there a way on Drupal 8 to remove "Not specified" and "Not applicable" languages from list and to display only listed Languages?

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Go to Manage form display of a content type and click on settings cog on right corner of Language field. There you will see a checkbox **Include locked languages such as Not specified and Not applicable** uncheck it to remove options like *Not specified* and *Not applicable*.

[image]